# Community Preference for Documentation-related STRI Modules

Tags: discussion

**Topic for discussion**: I've worked on and have wanted auto-generated Tridion documentation. How should we do it for STRI? For context, I often have to document Tridion Schemas after-the-fact.

Of the following, what would you recommend or prefer for an "STRI-friendly" approach?

- GUI extension like PowerTools Schema documenter
- Template that previews an item to show its (Schema) details
- PowerShell script
- Bookmarklet or JavaScript?

I'm thinking templates might be the easiest way to get contributors and have this in a folder as an STRI module. If so, would there be preference for the type of CM-side template (modular with XSLT, DWT, with C# TBBs)?

***Update***: Bart pointed out this could better fit a discussion, especially since any answers would be opinion-based (even his own).

Comment: As this is more a discussion type of question, I'm wondering if we should move it to Meta? Let's await some opinions

Comment: Being an STRI question made me think TRex proper, but I think SDL Community might fit better for a discussion. I was hoping someone like Bart Koopman (oh hi, Bart) would say, "definitely do it this way," but it seems STRI modules can be anything we want. I might just close this question and make something, Midas Rule style.

Comment: I'm not against the question, just it looks more like a discussion since the answes are opinion based (in which case we could move it to meta, or to community.sdl.com indeed). Who am I to say: "do it this way"? (even though my name is Bart ;o)

Comment: K, l'll try Meta first for the discussion and we'll see how modules evolve. :-)